# Как передать аргумент из одной функции в другую?

Tags: python, aiogram

Как я могу передать **driver** из первой функции во вторую? **(Не используя global)**

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=[''])
async def main_start(msg: types.Message):
    driver = driver_start()


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True)
async def callback_func(call: types.CallbackQuery, driver):
    login(driver)
```

Драйвер это

```
driver = Chrome(options=opt)
```

Comment: использовать машину состояний

Comment: я использовал ее, но она не сохраняет драйвер, выходит ошибка...

Comment: А что вы хотите вообще сделать?

Comment: Есть бот, который берет расписание. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы для каждого пользователя была своя сессия браузера. То есть если делать драйвер глобальным, то во время одновременного использования 2 или более участников сессия перекрещивается и данные вместе с ними тоже

Comment: вам не стоит вообще использовать селениум, представьте, вы развернули бота у себя на компьютере либо на сервере. И одновременно какое-то количество людей смотрит расписание, сервер нагружается кучей браузеров, что существенно замедлит работу. Используйте requests

Comment: С помощью requests я не могу нажимать кнопки, ибо сайт написан на php и там нет ссылок на отдельную вкладку...Также я получаю скриншот сайта, а requests такого нету...

Comment: Покажите сайт, почти всегда всё можно решить запросами